# Problem reading xml file from Zend

Tags: xml, zend-framework

I created a simple xml file to store name of stylesheets, where is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<skin>
    <stylesheets>
        <stylesheet>default.css</stylesheet>
    </stylesheets>
</skin>
```

Now I tried to read the data using the following code

```
protected function loadSkin() {
    $skinData = new Zend_Config_Xml('./template/'.$this -> _template.'/skins/'.$this -> _skin.'/skin.xml');
    var_dump($skinData);
    $stylesheets = $skinData -> stylesheets -> stylesheet -> toArray();
    if(is_array($stylesheets)) {
        foreach($stylesheets as $stylesheet) {
            $this -> view -> headLink() -> appendStylesheet('/template/'.$this -> _template.'/skins/' . $this -> _skin . '/css/' . $stylesheet);
        }
    }       
}
```

But its gives `Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object`. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is nothing wrong with your code. Its just a logical error. You have told `Zend_Config_Xml` to parse the stylesheet as an array. But since there is just one stylesheet you are giving, it will not parse it as an array.

Your Solution

> Just add another stylesheet to the xml file.

Like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<skin>
    <stylesheets>
        <stylesheet>default.css</stylesheet>
        <stylesheet>another.css</stylesheet>
    </stylesheets>
</skin>
```

Comment: Wow, such a silly error. Shall I accept your answer. But I dont want to called as your sockpuppet account.

Comment: Robin, I can't tell you that. You know what happned to others.

Comment: well, I will like to accept this, cause you gave me a correct solution. And +1 too

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `Zend_Config_Xml` for this. For starters, it expects to find "sections" in your XML (eg "production", "testing", "development"). There's also a fair amount of overhead introduced catering for the `zf` namespace.

Instead, just use SimpleXML

```
$skinData = simplexml_load_file('./template/'.$this->_template.'/skins/'.$this->_skin.'/skin.xml');
foreach ($skinData->stylesheets->stylesheet as $stylesheet) {
    $this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet(...);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but still can you help me debug what is going on wrong. BTW, Same type of coding is working for loading template info... (Shall I paste that too, but it is the same thing)

Comment: @mrN At a guess, I'd say it's the "section" functionality working against you however I don't have a PHP setup in front of me to test right now. Perhaps change your `var_dump` call to `var_dump($skinData->toArray());`

Comment: I would agree, that `Zend_Config_Xml` is generally used to store configuration information, but still what OP is attempting is possible, without providing the Application Enviroment. Because, a particular stage or node is only seletected if it is provided during initiation the class like new `Zend_Config_xml("path.xml","production")`

Answer (score 0):

I found the same...add the same css file again. 
Zend is going to print it just one time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<skin>
    <stylesheets>
        <stylesheet>style.css</stylesheet>
        <stylesheet>style.css</stylesheet>
    </stylesheets>
</skin>
```